# Convert File To Byte Array Given Its Path In Local Storage?

Tags: c#, xamarin

The following collection contains image paths in the local storage

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Paths;
```

These file paths are selected by the user and on the Xamarin Android Player they appear like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/img1.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Download/img2.jpg
```

Now the problem is the following - I want to convert these selected images (based on their paths) to byte arrays for uploading them to server.
In WPF/ ASP.Net this would be easily accomplished by the following code:

```
byte[] Convert = File.ReadAllBytes("somepath...");
```

However it appears that there is no such thing available in Xamarin.Forms.

**What functions do I need to use in order to in Xamarin.Forms convert image, based on its physical path in local storage to byte array?**

**- - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - -**

**UPDATE**

***@asp_net*** Trying to implement your solution:

In my PCL project I've added the following two files:

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    byte[] ReadAllByteS(string path);
}
```

and

```
public static class FileUtility
{
    public static IFileSystem FileSystem { get; set; }

    public static void SetUp(IFileSystem fs)
    {
        FileSystem = fs;
    }
}
```

On Android I've added the following file:

```
class SharedFileSytem : IFileSystem
{
    public byte[] ReadAllByteS(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

And I'm kinda lost at the initialization/registering part - I'm pretty sure I need to add *something* in my *MainActivity.cs* file.

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
//?
LoadApplication(new App());
```

Because currently, when I'm trying to execute the following code in my PCL code

```
FileUtility.FileSystem.ReadAllByteS(somepath);
```

I get the following error message:

```
"object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

Comment: Late to the game on this, but the accepted answer was my solution. What was missing is registering the dependency service in the MainActivity. Add the line Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<SharedFileSytem>(); in the OnCreate() over ridden method. Usage: Invoke the dependency service in PCL by calling DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().ReadAllByteS()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify things: System.IO is not available in Portable Class Libraries, which you seem to use. But it is of course available "in Xamarin.Forms".

Options:

1. Use Shared Projects instead of PCL.
2. Call platform-specific code from your PCL.

**Example**

Define an interface within your PCL.

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    byte[] ReadAllByteS(string path);
}
```

Implement it on each platform (or within a shared project for all platforms in this case).

```
// Could also be "IosFileSystem" or "SharedFileSytem"
public class DroidFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public byte[] ReadAllbytes(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

Register your implementation when your app starts (there are [libraries out there](http://www.ninject.org/) helping you with that).

```
public static class Utils
{
    public IFileSystem FileSystem { get; set; }

    public static void SetUp(IFileSystem fs)
    {
        FileSystem = fs;
    }
}
```

(`Utils` lives in your PCL but its SetUp method is being called from AppDelegate or your Main Activity.)

Use it:

```
Utils.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(...)
```

Comment: Hey. Sorry that for such a long reply. A while ago, I thought I had figured it out on my own, and the code was working, but few days ago, I realized that implementation had to be changed, so I'm looking into using your code instead. Could you look up to my updated question to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can load image into Memory stream and convert in to array,Something like this should work

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
 {   
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: Saw similar example online, not sure what the File is supposed to be though, since System.IO.File is not available in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: sorry my bad the file refers to a embedded resource, See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public async static Task<IFile> AsStorageFileAsync(this byte[] byteArray, string fileNameEx)
    {
        IFile file = await StorageData.LocalStorage().CreateFileAsync(fileNameEx, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var fileHandler = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {              
            byte[] dataBuffer = byteArray;
            await fileHandler.WriteAsync(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some context/words to explain why this is the answer!